# Storing big numbers in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery documentation says that the NUMERIC data type accepts up to 38 digits of precision but yet I couldn't store this as a number when creating a table:

92540646618304498066684287400725037055

Comment: Wondering - in what cases do you need to store this kind of number?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa IPv6 addresses, GUIDs, and other 128bit numbers instead of treating them as binary.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type), the `NUMERIC` data type is set to 38 digits of precision and 9 digits of scale.

Precision is the *total* number of digits and scale is the number digits *after* the decimal point, so the largest integer you can store will be 38 - 9 = 29 digits (to the left of the decimal point).

The official range of the data type is `-99999999999999999999999999999.999999999` to `99999999999999999999999999999.999999999`